# Sending out e-mail alerts when a scheduled job fails?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just wondering if I should wrap the entire `main` function and then do a `try/except` to catch any generic `Exception` and have it send out an e-mail with the name of the script and the error, or if there is a better way.

Comment: How are you running your scheduled jobs? Via `cron`?

Comment: Currently windows task scheder:/

Comment: I was going to suggest letting `cron` send mail for you when your script generates output, but I guess that won't work. However it looks like you can get similar behaviour from Windows Task Scheduler: https://superuser.com/questions/249103/make-windows-task-scheduler-alert-me-on-fail